# "Anyone of" v/s "Anybody from"

Tags: grammaticality

I know that the following sentence is grammatically correct:

> Is anyone of you guys in the library?

But the following sentence seems wrong:

> Is anybody of you guys in the library?

I think with "anybody" the sentence would transform to:

> Is anybody from you guys in the library?

Which of the the above two sentences involving "anybody" is correct?

Comment: The problem is confusing the pronoun _anyone_ (stressed on the first syllable) with the phrase _any one_ (stressed on _one_), meaning 'choose one'. That's the sense that's grammatical in the first sentence, but it's not the same meaning as _anybody_, which is negative polarity like _anyone_ (but not _any one_). That's the problem with written English -- it doesn't represent the sounds and the intonation.

Comment: I get "Hey, guys, is anybody in the library?

Comment: The first problem is that you seemed have assumed that "Anyone or anybody of/from" is the collocation. It is not. The collocations are *"Anyone [of/from NP]"* and *"Anybody [of/from NP]."* Because of the influences of Norman French on English, the adjuncts have an overlap in nuance and modify "anyone/anybody". -- **of** = associated with; **from** = originating in. The difference lies in the respective meaning of **anyone** and **anybody**.

Answer (score 0):

**Anybody from you* is incorrect. Google Ngram finds no record of it. The most idiomatic expressions are *anyone of you* and *anyone **among** you* (the latter being more formal):
[image]

[*From*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/from) is often confused by non-natives as a synonym of ***among*** because of their mother tongues. Same problem with mine: the same preposition is used to mean *among* and *from* (provenance, origin, cause etc.) *Not* the case in English.

Comment: This is because _anybody_ means _anyone at all_ rather than _any one of a group_.